# Question involving functions and permutations

Tags: functions, combinations

If $A=\{1,2,3,4\},B=\{a,b,c\}$, how many functions $A\to B$ are not onto?

My Try: so one element in $B$ shouldn't have a preimage in A so one element is excluded(for convenience) so for $4$ elements in $A$ there are $2$ in B hence total ways are $16$ then $2$ elements in $B$ don't have a pre image so $2^3$ ways. Thus total ways are $16+8=24$ . So this can be done for all $3$ elements. Hence total ways are $72$ but answer given is $45$

Comment: Not following your calculation.  There are $3^4=81$ functions in total.  How many are surjections?  Well...there are $3$ ways to choose the element that's hit twice, then $\binom 42=6$ ways to choose the pre-image of the doubled element and $2$ ways to assign the others.  Thus there are $3\times6\times2=36$ surjections.  Thus $81-36=45$ non-surjections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method more in line with how you seem to have been thinking:

For a function to not be onto, there must be **at least one** letter which is absent in the image.

Let $X_a$ be the functions where $a$ is absent in the image (*among possibly others too*), $X_b$ be the functions where $b$ is absent in the image (*among possibly others too*), $X_c$ be the functions where $c$ is absent in the image (*among possibly others too*).

The set of functions where at least one of these are absent in the image are then $X_a\cup X_b\cup X_c$

We count:  $|X_a\cup X_b\cup X_c| = |X_a|+|X_b|+|X_c|-|X_a\cap X_b|-|X_a\cap X_c|-|X_b\cap X_c|+|X_a\cap X_b\cap X_c|$ via inclusion exclusion principle.

We have $|X_a|= 2^4$ since for each element of $A$, we have two options for where to send it (*either $b$ or $c$ since it can't be sent to $a$*).  Similarly $|X_b|=|X_c|=2^4$

We have $|X_a\cap X_b|=1^4$ since for each element of $A$, we have only one option for where to send it (*only $c$ since it can't be sent to either of $a$ or $b$*).  Similarly $|X_a\cap X_c|=|X_b\cap X_c|=1$

Finally, note that $|X_a\cap X_b\cap X_c|=0$ since it is impossible for a function to avoid **all** of the codomain as an image.

Our total then is $|X_a\cup X_b\cup X_c| = |X_a|+|X_b|+|X_c|-|X_a\cap X_b|-|X_a\cap X_c|-|X_b\cap X_c|+|X_a\cap X_b\cap X_c|\\=16+16+16-1-1-1=45$ functions which are not onto.

Answer (score 3):

Let us denote a function using notation where
 $(abcc)$ corresponds to $f(1)=a, f(2)=b, f(3)=c, f(4)=c$

The number of ALL functions would be $3^4=81$

The number of functions which are Onto would be counting something like $(aabc), (bcba), ...$

There are $3$ choices to choose the duplicated alphabet, and $4!/2!=12$ ways to rearrange them, meaning $3*12=36$ onto functions exist.

Thus, there are $81-36=45$ non-onto functions.

Answer (score 1):

You overcounted the "one element excluded" mappings
(assuming they were supposed to be "*exactly* one element excluded").
Yes, there are $16$ ways to map $A$ onto the two remaining elements of $B$
after one element of $B$ is excluded, but if you exclude $a$ (for example),
then two of the mappings you produce in this way are the one that
maps everything to $b$ and the one that maps everything to $c$.

So if you take your $16$ mappings and multiply by $3$, you have not only
already counted all the mappings that exclude two elements of $B$,
you have counted each of those mappings twice.

So the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle applies, and rather than *add*
the "two elements excluded" mappings, you should *subtract* them
from the total.

Moreover, there are not $2^3$ ways to map the elements of $A$ if
two elements of $B$ are excluded; there is only *one* way:
all elements of $A$ onto the one remaining element of $B$.
But there are three different elements of $B$ that might be the
one remaining, so there are a total of $3$ mappings excluding two elements.

In conclusion,
$$ 48 - 3 = 45 $$
is the correct answer.

An alternative is to remove the "only one element of $B$" mappings from
the "one element excluded" mappings, so instead of $16$ mappings,
you have only the $14$ mappings that actually use *both* remaining
elements of $B$.
Then you can compute the total number of mappings as
$$ (14 \cdot 3) + 3 = 42 + 3 = 45. $$

Comment: Yes you are right